Windows BootCamp Battery backup Issue
I am running windows 11 on Macbook Pro 2019 using bootcamp.
I am really worried about the battery life. Battery Life is excellent on the Mac. On Windows Bootcamp its a whole other story. Its painful to see that windows has no battery optimization like that of the Mac-OS, which is excellent to say the least. I know its difficult when building an OS on generic hardware, but at-least something would have been nice.
My battery barely lasts 90 mins as compared to more than 4hrs on the MACOS for generic browsing and videos. Which means I am doing a couple of battery cycles a day. Which also means battery will be toast in a year.
Very devilishly cunning of Apple to give Boot-camp, but no native optimizations. Very cheap of Microsoft to not even try to build a simple battery limiter so that you can just plug it in and forget about it.
Have looked far and wide for a simple generic battery limiter, but it doesn't exist. All Windows machines, rely on the manufacturer to build in something at the BIOS level to do battery optimizations. So literally cant do anything on a boot-camp.
Has anyone who runs Boot-camp able to figure this problem out?
